# Print last line of text file

Tags: bash, awk

I have a text file like this:

```
    1.2.3.t
    1.2.4.t

    complete
```

I need to print the last non blank line and two line to last as two variable. the output should be:

```
 a=1.2.4.t
 b=complete
```

I tried this for last line: 
  b=`awk '/./{line=$0} END{print line}' myfile`
but I have no idea for a.

Comment: According to your comments to answer, that's not the output you want; you want to *assign* the last two non-empty lines to variables `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk 'NF{a=b;b=$0} END{print "a="a;print "b="b}' file
a=1.2.4.t
b=complete
```

Or, if you want to the real variable assignment

```
$ awk 'NF{a=b;b=$0} END{print a, b}' file 
  | read a b; echo "a="$a; echo "b="$b

a=1.2.4.t
b=complete
```

you may need -r option for `read` if you have backslashes in the values.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. it works. but I need these two lines as a variable. I mean after that I should be able to echo "$a"  and $b separately.

Comment: That use of `read` will strip leading and trailing blank spaces and interpret escape sequences. Always use `IFS= read -r var(s)` unless you have a specific reason not to an understand the effects. In this case you should probably just be doing something like `arr="$( awk '...' )"` anyway.

Answer (score 2):

```
grep . file | tail -n 2 | sed 's/^ *//;1s/^/a=/;2s/^/b=/'
```

Output:

```
a=1.2.4.t
b=complete
```